# Testing @ControllerAdvice with MockMvc Http Status error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I can not pass the test with MockMvc in my Spring Boot application.

My ControllerAdvice looks like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandlers extends BaseExceptionHandler {

    public ExceptionHandlers() {
        super(log);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(RunNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorResponse handleRunNotFoundController(final RunNotFoundException ex) {
        log.error("Run not found thrown", ex);
        return new ErrorResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), "RUN_NOT_FOUND", ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());

    }
}
```

and I have two test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(RunController.class)
public class RunControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private RunService runService;

//    @Before
//    public void setup() {
//        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(runService)
//                .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandlers())
//                .build();
//    }

    @Test
    public void getRunsTestCorrectValues() throws Exception {

        List<Run> list = prepareRunList();
        when(runService.getRuns()).thenReturn(list);

        mvc.perform(get("/api/runs")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(1))

    }

    @Test
    public void getRunsTestRunsNotFoundException() throws Exception {
        given(runService.getRuns()).willReturn(Collections.emptyList());

        mvc.perform(get("/api/runs")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

In this case when I have `setup()` commented test `getRunsTestCorrectValues()` passed and  `getRunsTestRunsNotFoundException()`  failed with:

[image]

In second case when I will uncomment `setup()` and re-run test I got `getRunsTestCorrectValues()` failed and `getRunsTestRunsNotFoundException()` passed with:

[image]

I think is something related with `setup()`. Does someone has any ideas?

Comment: mate, you are mocking `RunController` without `ExceptionHandlers`. Plus you are mixing integration tests with unit tests, I recommend to run integration tests with `@SpringBootTest` annotation ;)

Comment: what dou you mean by that "you are mocking RunController without ExceptionHandlers".
About mixing integration tests with unity you mean I should not test  for example ```.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").value(1))```?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't use mocks in integrations tests. With mocking tests are not verifying integrations between components

Comment: Just to clear things up. When I use mocks I write unit tests. Integrations test means no mocking is involved ? 
So in my case I just wrote unit tests? And integrations test are different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mocking **runService**, then you should simply keep your test cases,
so you should modify the second one like this, in order to throw an exception.

```
given(runService.getRuns()).willThrow(new RunNotFoundException("Not Found"));
```